# How to move files to a virtual directory using c#

Tags: c#, iis, windows-installer, virtual-directory

I have created a virtual directory programmatically. Now I wanted to upload an HTML file to the created virtual directory. How can I do this?

**Snippet:**

```
DirectoryEntry Rootdir =  new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root");
DirectoryEntry dir= Rootdir .Children.Add("MyDirectory", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
Directory.CreateDirectory(Rootdir .Properties["Path"].Value+"\\MyDirectory");
dir.Properties["Path"].Insert(0, Rootdir .Properties["Path"].Value + "\\MyDirectory");
dir.CommitChanges();
Rootdir .CommitChanges();
dir.close();
Rootdir.close();
```

Comment: Please goto the link below

[How to upload files to IIS Virtual Directory][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272029/how-to-upload-files-to-iis-virtual-directory

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to do?  You tagged this question as Windows-Installer and this isn't even close to how you'd use MSI to deploy web applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm");
File.Copy(fileInfo.FullName, Rootdir.Properties["Path"].Value + "\\MyDirectory" + "\\" + fileInfo.Name);
```